# SQL Server : conditional in where statement using colunm as a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to use a conditional case in the `where` clause using different conditional columns?

Please refer to the code below

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MemberInfo') is not null
drop table #MemberInfo  

DECLARE @GroupID varchar(60),
@Eoid varchar(60);

set @GroupID='23'    
set @Eoid = null;

select a.memberid, a.membername, a.groupid, a.eoid
from membermst a 
where
    case 
       when @GroupID is not null 
          then a.groupid = @GroupID // this is an error
       when @Eoid is not null 
          then a.eoid = @Eoid // this is an error    
       when @GroupID is null and @Eoid is null 
          then select all records // this is an error
end
```

These are the conditions of my filter

- if @GroupID is NOT null then the query will generate base on GroupID
- else if @Eoid is NOT null then the query will generate base on Eoid
- else if both GroupID and Eoid is null then select all records

Note this is the condition of my program

1. groupid and eoid can be null at the same time
2. either groupid or eoid can only have a value
3. if groupid has value then eoid is null
4. if eoid has value then groupid is null
5. groupid and cannot have a value at the same time. either one of then has a value only

Is this possible using a SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write `CASE` `WHEN` here, you can simply change your `WHERE` to

```
where (@GroupID IS NULL OR a.groupid = @GroupID) AND (@Eoid IS NULL OR a.eoid=@Eoid)
```

This way you will get all records if both `@GroupID` & `@Eoid`  are `NULL` and if specified it will match the records with respective ids.

Comment: wow. this works i thanks. I never expected that you can use null = null to generate all records. thank you for the new technique

Answer (score 1):

Just use regular boolean logic:

```
select m.memberid, m.membername, m.groupid, m.eoid
from membermst m
where (@GroupID is not null and a.groupid = @GroupID) or
      (@GroupID is null and @Eoid is not null and a.eoid = @Eoid) or
      (@GroupID is null and @Eoid is null)
```

This can actually be simplified to:

```
select m.memberid, m.membername, m.groupid, m.eoid
from membermst m
where (a.groupid = @GroupID) or
      (@GroupID is null and a.eoid = @Eoid) or
      (@GroupID is null and @Eoid is null)
```

The `is not null` comparisons are actually redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be done by:

```
select a.memberid, a.membername, a.groupid, a.eoid
    from membermst a 
    where    
    ((@GroupID is null)or((@GroupID is not null)and (a.groupid = @GroupID)))
```